# Is it possible for a user to have less than 1 reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

Is it possible, under whatever circumstances for a user to have less than 1 reputation on a Stack Exchange site?

Comment: Thanks for marking this as duplicate. I quickly found the answer below after posting the question.

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not.

From [How does "Reputation" Work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work?rq=1):

> No user's reputation may drop below one point; if an action would cause a user's reputation to drop below one point, that user's reputation is set to one point